# How to avoid usize going negative?

Tags: indexing, rust

I'm translating a chunk (2000 lines) of proprietary C code into Rust. In C, it is common to run a pointer, array index, etc. down, for as long as it is non-negative.  In Rust, simplified to the bone, it would look something like:

```
while i >= 0 && more_conditions { 
    more_work;
    i -= 1;
}
```

Of course, when `i` is `usize`, you get an under-overflow from subtraction.  I have learned to work around this by using `for` loops with `.rev()`, offsetting my indexes by one, or using a different type and casting with `as usize`, etc.

Usually it works, and usually I can make it legible, but the code I'm modifying is chock-full of indexes running towards each other, and eventually tested with `i_low > i_high`

Something like (in Rust)

```
loop {
    while condition1(i_low) { i_low += 1; }
    while condition2(i_high) { j_high -= 1; }
    if i_low > i_high { return something; }
    do_something_else;
}
```

Every now and then this panics, as `i_high` runs past 0.

I have been inserting a lot of `j_high >= 0 &&` in the code, and it become a lot less readable.

How do experienced Rust programmers avoid `usize` variables going to -1?

1. for loops?    `for i in (0..size).rev()`
2. casting?      `i as usize`, after checking for `i < 0`
3. offsetting your variable by one, and using `i-1` when safe?
4. extra conditionals?
5. catching exceptions?

Or do you just eventually learn to write programs around these situations?

---

Clarification: The C code is not broken - it has been supposedly in production for ten years, structuring video segments on multiple servers 24/7.  It is just not following Rust conventions - it often returns -1 as an index, it recurses with -1 for the low index of an array to process, and indexes go negative all the time.  All of these are handled before problems occurs - ugly, but functional.  Something like:

```
incident_segment = detect_incident(array, start, end);
attach(array, incident_segment);
store(array, start, incident_segment - 1);
process(array, incident_segment + 1, end);
```

In the above code, every single of the three resulting calls may be getting a segment index that's -1 (attach, store) or out of bounds (process)  It's handled, but after the call.

My Rust code appears to be working as well.  As a matter of fact, in order to deal with the negative usize, I added additional logic that pruned a number of recursions, so it runs about as fast as the C code (apparently faster, but that's also because I distributed the output on multiple drives)

The issue is that the client does not not want a full rewrite, and wants the 'native' programmers to be able to check the two programs against each other.  Based on the answers so far, I'm thinking that using i64 and casting/shadowing as needed may be the best way to produce code that's easy to read for the 'natives'.  Which I personally do not have to like...

Comment: Can't you use a `Vec`, `[T]` or array for actual arrays instead of using C style pointers? Rust makes an effort to not use pointer unless you're doing really low-level things.

Comment: @OptimisticPeach I stomped on your edit; it's a good one so I suggest re-applying it.

Comment: Your C code is already broken when iterating in C on a index one should use `size_t` and the same rule apply, there is no reason to allow a `size_t` to underflow in C, generally in C a while loop reverse would have `while (i > 0 && some_condition) { i--; some_instruction; }`, your actual code is an infinite loop or have undefined behavior if you use an signed integer. Your question is lack of [mcve] so it's impossible to give you an accurate answer.

Comment: Another option, in any language, is to move the termination condition check to the end of the loop (`do {} while()`-style). Rust doesn't have do-while keywords, but [you can reproduce the behaviour easily](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/1313#issuecomment-146665147).

Comment: If your goal is to move to Rust *without* it looking like Rust, your project seems pointless. If the other developers **don't want Rust**, nothing you can do will ever solve that "problem". I love Rust, but forcing it on a bunch of developers who are happier writing C is only bound to spread ill will (see "Rust Evangelism Strike Force" for examples). If you literally want to translate your C to Rust as *unidiomatically* as possible, use some tool like [C2Rust](https://c2rust.com/)

Comment: *The C code is not broken - it has been supposedly in production for ten years* — these two things are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: I don't see how this is relevant to the question, so it goes here, where no one but Shepmaster will read it. The system that's being updated is a Frankenstein monster of many parts, written in, at least, C, C++, C#, python. At some point, some packet handling was rewritten in Rust, and the clients were happy with it. Then I was hired to speed something up, in C, and they were happy with that as well. Then they asked me to see whether I could move some existing, third party C code to their packet handler. And they insist on it being in Rust, probably because they plan on sticking with Rust.

Comment: FWIW, if you *want* someone to read a comment on SO, you should mention them (@-username). I agree that this diversion isn't directly relevant to the question, which is also why I put it here in the comments. I doubt that the C++, C# or Python code look like idiomatic C code, so it seems silly to make the *Rust* code look like idiomatic C code. I understand that you are doing what you are being paid to do and likely don't actually care one way or the other, but if the Rust code isn't going to be idiomatic, it seems a waste of effor. You can write C in Rust, but why would you *want* to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to do it idiomatically:

```
for j in (0..=i).rev() {
    if conditions {
        break;
    }
    //use j as your new i here
}
```

Note the use of `..=i` here in the iterator, this means that it'll actually iterate including `i`: `[0, 1, 2, ..., i-1, i]`, otherwise, you end up with `[0, 1, 2, ..., i-2, i-1]`

Otherwise, here is the code:

```
while (i as isize - 1) != -2 && more_conditions { 
    more_work;
    i -= 1;
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=15a6d03a145f37c65b72db60b4b0d344&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

Comment: The playground link panicked with: `attempt to subtract with overflow`

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably start by using [`saturating_sub`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.usize.html#method.saturating_sub) (and `_add` for parallel structure):

```
while condition1(i_low) { i_low = i_low.saturating_add(1); }
while condition2(i_high) { j_high = j_high.saturating_sub(1); }
```

You need to be careful to ensure that your logic handles the value saturating at zero. You could also use more C-like semantics with [`wrapping_sub`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.usize.html#method.wrapping_sub).

Truthfully, there's no one-size-fits-all solution. Many times, complicated logic becomes simpler if you abstract it a bit, or turn it slightly sideways. You haven't provided any concrete examples, so we cannot give any useful advice. I solve way too many problems with iterators, so that's often my first solution.

> catching exceptions

Absolutely not. That's exceedingly inefficient and non-idiomatic.